# IPP and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I've been trying to get the .NET Dev Kit and Azure SDK to work with Visual Studio 2012 and am not having much luck. What am I missing?

The [Azure SDK installation instructions](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0300_windows_azure_program_for_quickbooksapi/0001_installing_the_windows_azure_sdk_2.0_for_quickbooksapi) don't work on VS 2012. When I search for anything Intuit-related from the VS Extension Manager, nothing comes up.

I tried installing from the VS Gallery but then there's no Intuit Anywhere menu in VS as shown in the VS 2010 screen shot. (These instructions are highly suspect, since Intuit has moved away from the "Intuit Anywhere" name. But given that the developer site was overhauled recently I would expect the instructions to be up to date.)

Is there an easy way to get this to work with VS 2012, or am I wasting my time? Am I better off just building everything from scratch? (We have done that in another project, just not with Azure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Plugin for Visual Studio has not been updated for Visual Studio 2012, the last supported version is 2010.

The code that the plugin generates is available as templates and sample code as well.
It includes the Oauth grant and handler pages, as well as the OpenId handlers.

regards,
Jarred